# Using liquibase, how to handle an object model that is a subset of database table

Tags: database, grails, grails-orm, liquibase

Some days I love my dba's, and then there is today...

In a Grails app, we use the database-migration plugin (based on Liquibase) to handle migrations etc.

All works lovely.

I have been informed that there is a set of db administrative meta data that we *must* support on every table.  This information has zero use to the app.

Now, I can easily update my models to accommodate this.  But that answer is ugly.

The problem is now at each migration, Liquibase/database-migration plugin, complains about the schema and the model being out of sync.

Is there anyway to tell Liquibase (or GORM) that columns x,y,z are to be ignored?

What I am trying to avoid is changesets like this:

> changeSet(author: "cwright (generated)", id: "1333733941347-5") {
>         dropColumn(columnName: "BUILD_MONTH", tableName: "ASSIGNMENT")  }

Which tries to bring the schema back in line with the model.  Being able to annotate those columns as not applying to the model would be a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, you're probably better off defining your own [mapping block](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#ormdsl) and taking control of the [Data Mapper](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) (what Hibernate essentially is) yourself at this point. If you need to take control of the way the database-integration plugin handles migrations, you might wanna [look at the source](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-database-migration/blob/master/src/groovy/grails/plugin/databasemigration/GormDatabase.groovy) or [raise an issue on the JIRA](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPDATABASEMIGRATION). Naively, mapping your columns explicitly in the domain model should allow you to bypass unnecessary columns from the DB.